# selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created from tab crashed using ChromeDriver Chrome Selenium Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I am having this error apparently when trying to access a url that the script requests, does not have a specific. I don't understand exactly why this error, but I want to treat it so as not to abort the script when it occurs.

This make duplicate, but not solution my problem: [How to avoid the error: selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created from tab crashed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59069926/how-to-avoid-the-error-selenium-common-exceptions-sessionnotcreatedexception-m)

code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
chrome_options.add_argument('--incognito')
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/driver/chromedriver", options=chrome_options)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts/page11.py", line 15, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(BASE_WEB_DRIVER, options=chrome_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 76, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created
from tab crashed
  (Session info: headless chrome=78.0.3904.108)
```

Chrome: `Google Chrome 78.0.3904.108` and driver: `ChromeDriver 78.0.3904.105 (60e2d8774a8151efa6a00b1f358371b1e0e07ee2-refs/branch-heads/3904@{#877})` are compatible.

Answer (score 7):

This error message...

```
  selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created
  from tab crashed
(Session info: headless chrome=78.0.3904.108)
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **Browsing Context** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

---

### Analysis and Solution

There are diverse solution to this issue. However as per [UnknownError: session deleted because of page crash from tab crashed](https://github.com/elgalu/docker-selenium/issues/20) this issue can be solved by either of the following solutions:

- Add the following `chrome_options`:

  ```
  chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
  ```
- Another option to make it work would be to add the `chrome_options` as **`--disable-dev-shm-usage`**. This will force Chrome to use the `/tmp` directory instead. This may slow down the execution though since disk will be used instead of memory.

  ```
  chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
  ```
- So effectively, you code block will be:

  ```
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

  chrome_options = Options()
  chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
  chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
  chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
  chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/driver/chromedriver', options=chrome_options)
  ```

---

### from tab crashed

**from tab crashed** was WIP(*Work In Progress*) with the *Chromium Team* for quite some time now which relates to *Linux attempting to always use /dev/shm for non-executable memory*. Here are the references :

- [**Linux: Chrome/Chromium SIGBUS/Aw, Snap! on small /dev/shm**](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=522853)
- [**Chrome crashes/fails to load when /dev/shm is too small, and location can't be overridden**](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=715363)
- As per [Comment61#Issue 736452](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=736452#c61) the fix seems to be have landed with **Chrome v65.0.3299.6**

---

### Reference

You can find a detailed discussion in [unknown error: session deleted because of page crash from unknown error: cannot determine loading status from tab crashed with ChromeDriver Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53902507/unknown-error-session-deleted-because-of-page-crash-from-unknown-error-cannot/53970825#53970825)

Comment: I applied the correction as suggested, but still the same error. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I had same issue Script running independetly well. but inside from my webapplication(odoo) not running and giving same error.

Comment: Options specified here worked for me for similar error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I spent more than 4 hours by trying so many things like I used addArguements(), tried another version of chrome driver but nothing worked
After that I just restart my system and the problem was resolved. There is some memory issue.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32715173)