# Chromedriver in Python error SessionNotCreatedException

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to use Selenium and Chromedriver in Python. I am currently using PyCharm. I have the chromedriver.exe file saved in my Downloads and it is up to date with the Chrome version I am using.

The file path is "*C:\Users\ea.palacios\Downloads\chromedriver.exe*'

My script reads as:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\Users\\ea.palacios\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe')
```

I have also tried removing the double back-slashes:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\Users\ea.palacios\Downloads\chromedriver.exe')
```

When I tried running either script, a browser briefly appeared for less then a second before immediately closing. Then PyCharm returned the following message:

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\marcd.admin\PycharmProjects\PLDT\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\Users\\ea.palacios\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe')
  File "C:\Users\marcd.admin\PycharmProjects\PLDT\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 76, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "C:\Users\marcd.admin\PycharmProjects\PLDT\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\marcd.admin\PycharmProjects\PLDT\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\marcd.admin\PycharmProjects\PLDT\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\marcd.admin\PycharmProjects\PLDT\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created
from tab crashed
  (Session info: chrome=92.0.4515.107)
```

Here is a [screenshot of code and error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6SS4.png)

Could this be happening because I am running PyCharm as an Administrator on my work computer but the Chromedriver is saved in my regular downloads folder? Really no clue! Help! Please and thanks.

Comment: What is your Google Chrome browser version ?

Comment: It's Version 92.0.4515.107 @cruisepandey

Comment: you can use automatic downloader, you don't have to give manual path of chrome driver. See below for more details.

Comment: You can once check this [Sessionnotcreated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59186984/16452840).

Comment: @EaPalacios can you check if the system's antivirus or firewall have blocked the chromedriver, chrome from executing

Answer (score 1):

Use :-

## chromedriver-autoinstaller

i.e. :

> Automatically download and install chromedriver that supports the
> currently installed version of chrome. This installer supports Linux,
> MacOS and Windows operating systems.

## Installation

```
pip install chromedriver-autoinstaller
```

**Usage**

Just type `import chromedriver_autoinstaller` in the module you want to use `chromedriver`.

**Example**

```
from selenium import webdriver
import chromedriver_autoinstaller


chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()  # Check if the current version of chromedriver exists
                                      # and if it doesn't exist, download it automatically,
                                      # then add chromedriver to path

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
```

Comment: My google chrome browser is `92.0.4515.107` and I am using the automatic installer, and it is working fine.

Comment: Hi! I tried running the code but unfortunately the same error message pops up.

Comment: It should work as I have the same configuration, try to reboot and see if that helps

Answer (score 0):

> **You could use this solution. It will do two things:**
>
> 1. Check locally in your computer for the driver version and compare
>    it with the latest version available online.
> 2. The latest online version will be automatically **downloaded** if it
>    does not match your local version.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import requests
import zipfile
import wget
import subprocess
import os


CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = "" # Insert your Chromedriver path here
CHROMEDRIVER_FOLDER = os.path.dirname(CHROMEDRIVER_PATH)
LATEST_DRIVER_URL = "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE"


def download_latest_version(version_number):
    print("Attempting to download latest driver online......")
    download_url = "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/" + version_number + "/chromedriver_win32.zip"
    # download zip file
    latest_driver_zip = wget.download(download_url, out=CHROMEDRIVER_FOLDER)
    # read & extract the zip file
    with zipfile.ZipFile(latest_driver_zip, 'r') as downloaded_zip:
        # You can chose the folder path to extract to below:
        downloaded_zip.extractall(path=CHROMEDRIVER_FOLDER)
    # delete the zip file downloaded above
    os.remove(latest_driver_zip)


def check_driver():
    # run cmd line to check for existing web-driver version locally
    cmd_run = subprocess.run("chromedriver --version",
                             capture_output=True,
                             text=True)
    # Extract driver version as string from terminal output
    local_driver_version = cmd_run.stdout.split()[1]
    print(f"Local driver version: {local_driver_version}")
    # check for latest chromedriver version online
    response = requests.get(LATEST_DRIVER_URL)
    online_driver_version = response.text
    print(f"Latest online chromedriver version: {online_driver_version}")
    if local_driver_version == online_driver_version:
        return True
    else:
        download_latest_version(online_driver_version)
```